# Simple JavaScript Object Constructor

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

I'm reading a [beginner's guide](http://burakkanber.com/blog/machine-learning-in-js-k-nearest-neighbor-part-1/) on machine learning from scratch with JavaScript.

About a 1/4 way down the page is the section titled "**THE CODE**". Right under that section heading is the code in question.

```
var Node = function(object) {  
    for (var key in object)
    {
        this[key] = object[key];
    }
};
```

I realize this could be a very basic constructor function but I've never seen this pattern before.

Is there any links or guides about this pattern design or type of constructor. I'd like to learn as much as possible as I can about it.

Comment: Looks like what you could call a "copy constructor".

Comment: Copying one object's properties into a new object instead of typing this.prop=1 (etc) manually. Someone from C++ background is having fun with EcmaScript 6 for-in loop.

Comment: @InfiniteStack [for-in is defined in ES1...](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf)

Comment: Oh crap you're right. I mixed it up with for...of.  @Patrick Roberts

Comment: @InfiniteStack - `for..of` has been added to JS now too.

Comment: Yes in ES6 @nnnnnn

Comment: The circle is complete…

Comment: What would be a better idiomatic js way to do a copy constructor?

Comment: @qarthandso The constructor should know what properties to expect, and only explicitly assign those.

Comment: @Bergi can you elaborate on what you mean by it _should know what properties to expect_?

Comment: @qarthandso The guide explicitly states "*It just expects an object with the properties "type", "area", and "rooms".*" So the code should reflect that and read `this.type = object.type; this.area = object.area; this.rooms = object.rooms;` instead of that loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much to learn about or understand. It's simply constructing a new object and copying the properties from some other object into it.

In modern JS, you could also write

```
function Node(object) {
  Object.assign(this, object);
}
```

Comment: It's a constructor when it's supposed to be called with `new`. We cannot really judge that from the code, the only hint we have is the capitalisation of the function name.